# Lists in a provider hosted app

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app

I created a provider hosted web app and added a list to it.  I can see the list is in the app web using spmanager however i couldnt get a simple link on the apps default.aspx page to work correctly.  i was using `<a href="../Lists/TestList/">Test List</a>` but it was incorrect.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

That is saying go up a level (..) and navigate to Lists/TestList. You want simply:

```
<a href="Lists/TestList/">Test List</a>
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either.  The default.aspx page is in the pages library so i would think you need to go up a level to access the lists